# Automatically install packages/dependencies for installation of an arbitrary package?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

**Scenario**

When starting with a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 installation, my goal is to solely install and use the package `default-jre` as quickly as possible for debugging purposes. I can install this by running the commands:

`yes | sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

and:

`yes | sudo apt install default-jre`

However the first command takes approximately 30 minutes on my current device, and whilst it is a great exercise thinking well about my code before I run it, I am trying to increase the speed at which I can test my code, which means increasing the speed with which I can execute a `.jar` file starting from a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 installation.

**Attempts**

First I solely ran:

```
yes | sudo apt install default-jre
```

And that returned:

```
a@DESKTOP-:~$ yes | sudo apt install default-jre --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre-headless fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core fonts-dejavu-extra
  hicolor-icon-theme java-common libasound2 libasound2-data libasyncns0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libavahi-client3
  libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcairo2 libcups2 libdatrie1 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2
  libdrm-radeon1 libflac8 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgif7 libgl1-mesa-dri
  libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libgraphite2-3 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libharfbuzz0b libjbig0
  libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 libllvm6.0 libnspr4 libnss3 libnss3-nssdb libogg0 libpango-1.0-0
  libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpciaccess0 libpcsclite1 libpixman-1-0 libpulse0 libsensors4 libsndfile1
  libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libx11-xcb1 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0
  libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1
  libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxtst6 libxxf86vm1 openjdk-8-jre
  openjdk-8-jre-headless x11-common
Suggested packages:
  default-java-plugin libasound2-plugins alsa-utils cups-common librsvg2-common gvfs liblcms2-utils pcscd pulseaudio
  lm-sensors icedtea-8-plugin libnss-mdns fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-wqy-microhei
  fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre default-jre-headless fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core
  fonts-dejavu-extra hicolor-icon-theme java-common libasound2 libasound2-data libasyncns0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data
  libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcairo2 libcups2 libdatrie1 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-intel1
  libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libflac8 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgif7
  libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libgraphite2-3 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common
  libharfbuzz0b libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 libllvm6.0 libnspr4 libnss3 libnss3-nssdb libogg0
  libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpciaccess0 libpcsclite1 libpixman-1-0 libpulse0 libsensors4
  libsndfile1 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libx11-xcb1 libxcb-dri2-0
  libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1
  libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxtst6 libxxf86vm1 openjdk-8-jre
  openjdk-8-jre-headless x11-common
0 upgraded, 83 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 28.8 MB/57.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 341 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libavahi-common-data amd64 0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libavahi-common3 amd64 0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libavahi-client3 amd64 0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libcups2 amd64 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libnss3-nssdb all 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libnss3 amd64 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Ign:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libtiff5 amd64 4.0.6-1ubuntu0.4
Err:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common all 2.32.2-1ubuntu1.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 amd64 2.32.2-1ubuntu1.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Ign:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libcups2 amd64 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libnss3-nssdb all 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libnss3 amd64 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libtiff5 amd64 4.0.6-1ubuntu0.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/avahi/libavahi-common-data_0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/avahi/libavahi-common3_0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/avahi/libavahi-client3_0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libcups2_2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5_amd64.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3-nssdb_3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3_all.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3_3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3_amd64.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tiff/libtiff5_4.0.6-1ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gdk-pixbuf/libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common_2.32.2-1ubuntu1.5_all.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gdk-pixbuf/libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0_2.32.2-1ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre_8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gdk-pixbuf/libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common_2.32.2-1ubuntu1.5_all.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gdk-pixbuf/libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0_2.32.2-1ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre_8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Hence I tried:

```
yes | sudo apt install default-jre --fix-missing
```

But that returned:

```
a@DESKTOP-:~$ yes | sudo apt install default-jre --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre-headless fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core fonts-dejavu-extra
  hicolor-icon-theme java-common libasound2 libasound2-data libasyncns0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libavahi-client3
  libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcairo2 libcups2 libdatrie1 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2
  libdrm-radeon1 libflac8 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgif7 libgl1-mesa-dri
  libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libgraphite2-3 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libharfbuzz0b libjbig0
  libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 libllvm6.0 libnspr4 libnss3 libnss3-nssdb libogg0 libpango-1.0-0
  libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpciaccess0 libpcsclite1 libpixman-1-0 libpulse0 libsensors4 libsndfile1
  libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libx11-xcb1 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0
  libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1
  libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxtst6 libxxf86vm1 openjdk-8-jre
  openjdk-8-jre-headless x11-common
Suggested packages:
  default-java-plugin libasound2-plugins alsa-utils cups-common librsvg2-common gvfs liblcms2-utils pcscd pulseaudio
  lm-sensors icedtea-8-plugin libnss-mdns fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-wqy-microhei
  fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre default-jre-headless fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core
  fonts-dejavu-extra hicolor-icon-theme java-common libasound2 libasound2-data libasyncns0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data
  libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcairo2 libcups2 libdatrie1 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-intel1
  libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libflac8 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgif7
  libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libgraphite2-3 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common
  libharfbuzz0b libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 libllvm6.0 libnspr4 libnss3 libnss3-nssdb libogg0
  libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpciaccess0 libpcsclite1 libpixman-1-0 libpulse0 libsensors4
  libsndfile1 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libx11-xcb1 libxcb-dri2-0
  libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-sync1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1
  libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxtst6 libxxf86vm1 openjdk-8-jre
  openjdk-8-jre-headless x11-common
0 upgraded, 83 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 28.8 MB/57.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 341 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libavahi-common-data amd64 0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libavahi-common3 amd64 0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libavahi-client3 amd64 0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libcups2 amd64 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libnss3-nssdb all 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libnss3 amd64 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Ign:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libtiff5 amd64 4.0.6-1ubuntu0.4
Err:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common all 2.32.2-1ubuntu1.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 amd64 2.32.2-1ubuntu1.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Ign:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libcups2 amd64 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libnss3-nssdb all 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libnss3 amd64 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libtiff5 amd64 4.0.6-1ubuntu0.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/avahi/libavahi-common-data_0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/avahi/libavahi-common3_0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/avahi/libavahi-client3_0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libcups2_2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3-nssdb_3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3_3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tiff/libtiff5_4.0.6-1ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gdk-pixbuf/libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common_2.32.2-1ubuntu1.5_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gdk-pixbuf/libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0_2.32.2-1ubuntu1.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre_8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Aborting install.
```

Based on [How to run 'apt-get install' to install all dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214746/how-to-run-apt-get-install-to-install-all-dependencies) I tried the following command after `yes | sudo apt install default-jre` returned perhaps run with `--fix-missing`?

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Which returned:

```
DESKTOP-:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfreetype6
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Now using the feedback of the `yes | sudo apt install default-jre` I could select the required packages and generate a list of commands that installs those packages specifically potentially circumventing the `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` command.

**Question**

But I was curious whether there is a command that automatically installs the required packages/dependencies when you run it to install `<some package>`?

Comment: I noticed that too, but I did not use a proxy nor vpn at the time of running the `yes | sudo apt install default-jre --fix-missing` command. Nor during any of the other commands. Also the combination of `yes | sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and `yes | sudo apt install default-jre` does always work. So I assumed it was my knowledge gap that led to me not understanding how the `--fix-missing` command led to network problems. I currently can not give any reasons for those network problems, I do not experience them in any other way shape or form.

Comment: Just to make things more clear: do you really forgot to run `sudo apt-update` before running `sudo apt install default-jre`?

Comment: I apologize, I did forget to run `sudo apt-update` before running `sudo apt install default-jre`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the 404 errors because the package indexes that come with your fresh install are out of date, hence they cause Apt to try to fetch old packages which no longer exist. To refresh your indexes you must run `sudo apt update`. Running `sudo apt upgrade` however is not required, in the sense that `sudo apt install default-jre` will work even if you don't run `sudo apt upgrade`. Not running it, however, will leave you with out-of-date packages, which may contain bugs. Proceed at your own risk.

Comment: I found this to contain the essence of the problem. I did not think about running the `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` commands separately anymore due to habit. My apologies. I verified your solution by first running: `yes | sudo apt update` followed by `yes | sudo apt install default-jre`. From this I conclude that my question should not be relevant; Ubuntu 16.04 automatically installs and downloads the required packages/dependencies for `sudo apt install default-jre`, as long as your reference list of where to get those packages is up-to-date.  (The `--fix-missing` was not required.)